# Maven Replacer Plugin StringUtil Issue

Tags: maven

I'm trying to implement [Maven Replacer Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/wiki/UsageGuide) in my build.

However I am stuck with this issue :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:1.5.2:replace (default) on project ReportBCSIS: Execution default of goal com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:1.5.2:replace failed: A required class was missing while executing com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:1.5.2:replace: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:1.5.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/grudy/.m2/repository/com/google/code/maven-replacer-plugin/replacer/1.5.2/replacer-1.5.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/grudy/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Below is my current pom configuration :

```xml
    <plugin>
       <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
       <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.2</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>prepare-package</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>replace</goal>
               </goals>                   
           </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
           <file>target/${project.artifactId}/index.jsp</file>
           <replacements>
               <replacement>
                   <token>BUILDID-TOKEN</token>
                   <value>121212-HAHA</value>
               </replacement>         
           </replacements>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Isnt the usual filtering not enough? Furthermore the problem is the plugin, cause it doesn't defined the correct dependencies.

Comment: looks like commons-lang and commons-id dependencies are missing as it is needed by Maven Replacer Plugin. [Ref Pom](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/source/browse/trunk/pom.xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding text below inside plugin does the trick :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```